# Thunderbird forwarding without rewriting reply-to

Tags: email, forwarding, headers, thunderbird

We have a secondary email account for our business, and a mail rule on one of our installations of thunderbird that forwards anything coming in on that account to the other account (the one we actually check). It's working well enough, apart from the fact that we keep hitting reply and sending ourselves (the secondary account) an email (which ends up getting forwarded back to our main account).

What I was wondering is if anyone knew of a way to get thunderbird to leave the reply-to header alone when forwarding these emails - I'm assuming if possible it would require an extension as I can't see anything in the stock UI that would let me do this.

I know the best way to do this would be getting our email provider to forward it all for us, but that would require more competence and willingness to help their customers than they have shown so far.

Comment: Use server side forwarding.

Comment: Would love to 'Use server side forwarding'. Except the servers aren't ours, and, as mentioned in the original question: "I know the best way to do this would be getting our email provider to forward it all for us, but that would require more competence and willingness to help their customers than they have shown so far."